# Why does the C# compiler say that string does not have a `Contains` method

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2013, c#-5.0

Why does the C# compiler say that string does not have a `Contains` method?

- the `errors` object is `List<Error>`
- `Error.Message` is `string`

For this statement

```
Assert.True(errors.Any(e => e.Message.Contains("hash value",
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

the compiler says:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)` has some invalid arguments

And for this statement, the compiler is happy:

```
Assert.True(errors.Any(e => e.Message.IndexOf("hash value", 
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

Comment: There's only one [`System.String.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and it doesn't have two parameters. What did you think was going to happen?

Comment: The signature of the `String.Contains` method is `public bool Contains(string value)`.

Comment: Perhaps the question should say "why does the compiler say that `string` does not contain a definition for `Contains`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the C# compiler getting confused about which `Contains` to use, or am I?

You are.

The right method is `IndexOf()`, not `Contains()`. There is only one `string.Contains()` overload (if you could call it that), and [it doesn't take a `StringComparison` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx).

Comment: I thought Contains also supported StringComparison but that must have been an extension method I've used elsewhere that wasn't available in this code. Thanks for the civil reply instead of the snark in the replies to my question.

Comment: Fwiw, the compiler error had me looking down the wrong path since it said string didn't have "Contains" at all.